# After finally installing 16.04, I have no internet connection - ethernet cable doesn't work, but Wi-Fi is connected to the network?

Tags: network-manager, internet

After I installed 16.04 and finally booted up, my wireless network was detected and I could connect to it, my communication with router is ok, I can access it, but there is no internet connection, and if I try connecting with ethernet cable nothing happens, not detected.

Things I've tried as suggested solutions in some other posts I found:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and then changing the state from false to true. Nothing

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

changing "iface lo inet loopback" to "iface lo inet dhcp". Nothing

Tried

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

No luck.

From another Windows PC with connection I downloaded various dkms and build-essential .deb files, transfered them on USB to ubuntu and ran them since I can't run sudo apt-get with no connection. Ran them with "sudo dpkg" until one of them went fine with no errors (I'm no Linux expert so i'm guessing I installed the right ones). But still my problem persists.

Built-in LAN function in BIOS is enabled.

I had different problem previously with booting my system. On the same computer my Windows would freeze upon logo, so I decided to say bye to Windows and format the whole drive and put Ubuntu. The system was still freezing upon booting anything. The only thing i could do was set UEFI mode in BIOS and run LiveUSB with acpi=off, that was the only way i could boot LiveUsb.

So i ran the installation that way but DIDN'T FORCE UEFI install. Changed it back to CMS later in BIOS and i still got freeze upon booting ubuntu. So after 5 days of struggle I read somewhere that removing the laptop battery and holding the power button for 30 sec and then putting the battery back in would work...and IT DID.

So here i am with a working ubuntu and no internet connection. The thing is in one of the previous installation processes I had a working connection just fine.

I have a Toshiba Satellite C50-B. Here are some of the outputs.

```
 ifconfig

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:161456 (161.4 KB)  TX bytes:161456 (161.4 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:cf:5e:29:4d:17  
          inet addr:192.168.1.36  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6654:7217:923e:2868/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63585 (63.5 KB)  TX bytes:14951 (14.9 KB)
```

---

```
lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

---

```
nmcli dev

DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
wlp2s0  wifi      connected  MyConnection  
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

---

```
lshw

       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlp2s0
            version: 01
            serial: 18:cf:5e:29:4d:17
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:17 memory:d0700000-d077ffff memory:d0780000-d078ffff
```

I'm a former Ubuntu user finally coming home. I would appreciate any help because I have no clue what to do anymore.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your internet? If you can talk to your router but not the open web, it seems like a DNS issue. What websites have you tried to access? Have you tried accessing IP addresses instead of domain names? Try http://198.252.206.140/

Comment: I'm pretty sure DNS is the issue, pinging 8.8.8.8. is succesful, I can also ping 198.252.206.140 and access it with firefox to get to Stack Exchange. Note that I don't have all the proper repositories set up and had trouble installing some. I managed to install dkms and bcmwl-kernel-source, both gave me trouble with Possible missing firmware error (something about module i915) which I managed to fix by installing the appropriate KabyLake and Broxton firmware. I'm not sure how to fix the rest of the repositories and dependecy issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem after all. What I did:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Comment out the following line with #:

dns=dnsmasq  ---> (to #dns=dnsmasq)

Also I did:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Pressed OK twice and restarted the computer - Internet working fine I'm not sure which of the two actions had the desired effect but it's all good now. All I have to do now is fix the unmet dependecies which I believe will be no problem with a working connection.

Thanks for the reply, you helped me get on the right track.
Cheers.